# How to fill NotMapped property with count in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have added the following property to PassAllocations class :

```
[NotMapped]
public int PendingForApprovalCount { get; set; }

 var passAllocations = db.PassAllocations.Include(p => p.PassRule)
.Where(p => p.CompanyID == company.CompanyID).ToList();
```

I am trying to fill each `PendingForApprovalCount` property in list passAllocations with result of `db.PassLinkings.Where(p => p.PassAllocationID == parentid and p.status="Pending").ToList()`

Where 'parentid' is `PassAllocationID` in each `passAllocations` list

Comment: Please post you `PassLocation` class and class from which you want to extract  `PendingForApprovalCount`

Answer (score 0):

```
passAllocations
.ForEach(x=>x.PendingForApprovalCount=db.PassLinkings
                                        .Where(p => p.PassAllocationID == x.id &&
                                                    p.status="Pending")
                                        .Count())
```

It might give you correct result but this is not at all advisable solution as it will led to multiple hits to db ,which will eventually hamper performance. A better solution may be this one

```
var desiredResult=(from a in db.PassAllocations
                               .Include(pa => pa.PassRule)
                               .Where(pa => pa.CompanyID == company.CompanyID)
                   join b in db.PassLinkings
                               .Where(pl => pl.status="Pending")
                               .GroupBy(pl=>pl.PassAllocationID)
                   on a.PassAllocationID equals b.Key
                   select new {a,b})
                  .Select(x=>new PassAllocation
                             {
                              PassAllocationID=x.a.PassAllocationID,
                              .
                              .  
                              .   <------------Other Properties
                              .
                              .
                              PendingForApprovalCount=x.b.Count()
                              }).ToList();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was actually looking for a way to avoid having to explicitly bind `Other properties`

Comment: @Arbaaz then my friend you should have foreignKey reference or go with 1st peice of code which is not at all advisable